# QGIS Add geopackages of the current project as geopackage connection to the browser panel

Tags: qgis, geopackage, connection, pyqgs

My first approach would have been to query the project's layer for their source and type and then add it to the [providers] section of QGIS3.ini. I assume the ini only gets loaded on startup so I doubt that this is a viable solution, is it?
My second approach would include a deep dive into the [QgsPrividerRegistry](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.32/core/QgsProviderRegistry.html) but I wonder if the script isn't already out there since this is a step frequently needed.